# I have chained multiple async monos and want to do proper error handling in case first one fails

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
return Mono.zip(mono1, mono2, mono3)
      .doOnError( err -> loggerUtil.error()
      .flatMap(res -> {
             loggerUtil.info();
                 return readPersistenceDAOHandler.upsertOfferInReadCollection(params);
              })
      .map(obj -> {
                  loggerUtil.info();
                  return obj;
                })
    .doOnError( err-> )
                .retryWhen(RetryPolicy.retryOnPersistenceFailed(commonConfig.getFailureRetryCount(), commonConfig.getFailureRetryBackoffInMs()));
```

So here basically what I am trying to do is, on success of mono.zip , perform another asynchronous operation. Now if mono.zip fails I want to log the error , but with this chaining how do I whether first async operation failed or whether 2nd one failed, bcoz the 2nd doOnError that I have used will be invoked in both the cases.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, The cleanest solution lies in having a well defined error domain. Error handling methods on mono mostly use the type of the exception in order to identify the handling that needs to be performed. So, ideally, each of your monos would fail with a different exeption. One can then chain a couple of those error handling method calls

```
zipped.doOnError(Mono1Exception.class, handle1())
.doOnError(Mono2Exception.class, handle2())
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no straightforward method to identify which mono has failed. One possible workaround is to enclose the mono's exception in your custom exception, but this is not the most elegant solution.

```java
Mono.zip(
    mono1.onErrorMap(e -> new Service1Exception(e)),
    mono2.onErrorMap(e -> new Service2Exception(e)),
    mono3.onErrorMap(e -> new Service3Exception(e))
)
        .doOnError(Service2Exception.class, e -> ...)
```

Can you please provide further information about your situation? I'm not recalling any similar instances from my experience. Perhaps there could be an alternative solution without identifying the specific mono that has failed.